# Force Anchor ID into page URL

Tags: url, craft-features

I'm trying to add tabs into my Craft Site and have just noticed that when you add an anchor point, the anchor ID doesn't actually show up in the URL as it would a normal site, however I need this anchor to be able to target certain tabs in the menu.

Is there a way or plugin that forces to anchor to be added to the url?

Example:

mysite.com/tabs#anchor1

mysite.com/tabs#anchor2

mysite.com/tabs#anchor3

Answer (score 1):

Craft CMS does absolutely nothing to your front end code, and there's literally nothing in Craft that would make anchor links – i.e. `<a href="/tabs#anchor1">Click</a>` – in your front end markup behave in any other way than normal.

The error is probably somewhere in your front end code (either in your Twig/markup or possibly in your JavaScript).

Comment: Afraid I haven't added any javascript in at this point, my markup is exactly how you've just laid it out there which is why I can't understand why it doesn't show